# Calling a method relating to an object in an arrayList through clicking a specific label

Tags: java, arraylist, mouseevent, jlabel, joptionpane

I am trying to implement a feature in a project that I am working on but I am having dificulties. The project allows the user to create 3 different objects that all share the same super class. Each object is part of an arrayList and is represented by an ImageIcon inside of a JLabel. I would like to be able to click a specific JLabel and open a message dialog with a toString() method that returns information about the coresponding object.

So far, I have a (poorly implemented) system in place that will allow the user to click any ImageIcon but it will only display information about the most recently created object. I am aware why this code only displays the information it does but I do not know how create the code that I need.

If anyone can help I would be very grateful. If anything is poorly explained or needs elaborating on, please ask. I have attached my current code below, Thank you.

Code explanation: The 'count' variable is used to count the number of objects created (I cannot have more that 9). I know that the current code will just display the 'count-1' object created (which is the newest one). I'm just un aware of what I need to do to find the specific object relating to the lable that is clicked.

```
label[count].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, myAppliances.get(count-1).toString()); 
            }});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Each object is part of an arrayList and is represented by an ImageIcon inside of a JLabel.

That gives a good hint to it. How about doing following

Class MyObjectLabel extends JLabel something like below:

```
public MyObjectLabel extends JLabel
{
   private YourObjectThatisInList localCopyOfObject;
   public MyObjectLabel (YourObjectThatisInList object)
   {
     super(createIconForTheObject(object));
     this.localCopyOfObject=object
   }
    //add getter setter method for localCopyOfObject
}
```

2) Now add listener to this class.

3) On event fired of this new Label class, call the getter for localCopyOfObject and display the toString for your localCopyOfObject stored in MyObjectLabel.

Please note that createIconForTheObject, is just a placeholeder method I showed. You can use your own method to create icon

Thanks